# Why it takes so long for intelliJ IDEA to build a Hello world in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I created a simple Hello world Java program. Every time I change a single line of the file in IntelliJ (not even adding any code, just add a blank new line), and then run it, it will take **2.5~3.5 sec** to build it and run.

If I don't change anything and just rerun it, it will take like 1 sec.

**Why it take so long to build just a hello world program? Is this normal?**

[Building time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWDq9.png)

---

I am switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. This is a new IntelliJ just installed without any plugin.

I tried to change the settings, increase the heap size, none of those help.
[Heap Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEn0K.png)

I do not have any anti-virus except the Windows Defender. I don't think this is causing any trouble.

I tried to search online, they are mostly talking about slow build time in large projects, but mine is just a simple hello world program, and I don't think it should have such problem.

When I use Eclipse in the same computer, I run the code (not only a simple hello world program), and the output will take less than 0.5 sec to show up.

Using Windows 10, IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 x64.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with inteliJ but my best guess is that you chose the wrong type of project to just develop a hello world program, which as a consequence IJ is using a bunch on unnecessary tools to "build" your program: compile, generate a jar, running java agent (as your image shows) and finally running it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment so this page can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @JorgeCampos After seeing your comment, I tried its official tutorial, following each step by step and the problem is still there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_XxH66lm3U&feature=emb_title&ab_channel=IntelliJIDEAbyJetBrains

Comment: The same thing takes 1200ms on my computer

Comment: When I change the code re-run takes about 2.6sec b/c of compilation. But when I do not change anything rerun is instant and I see `All files are up-to-date` message. Do you have a sense that you wait more than that? Check Windows Defender options, try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs) IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan. If project/IDE settings directories are located not on a local drive it also could take longer time to build.

Answer (score 0):

When I change the code re-run takes about 2.6sec b/c of compilation. But when I do not change anything rerun is instant and I see `All files are up-to-date` message.

[image]

Do you have a sense that you wait more than that? Check Windows Defender options, try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs) IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan. If project/IDE settings directories are located not on a local drive it also could take longer time to build.

Comment: If I don't change anything and just rerun, it will take 0.7~1sec (_Its not accurate, but surly not instant, as I mentioned, if I am in eclipse, changing the code or not, will take 0.1~0.5sec for most of my any codes._), it does show `All files are up-to-date`. Also, I feel like taking about `2.6sec b/c of compilation` is already a problem. I will try to disable my Windows Defender later to check.

Comment: Im having the same issue, did windows defender have anything to do with it? @Nor.Z

Comment: @CameronWard I didn't test it out. But base on my search, the speed is just how it is. It should not have anything to do with Windows Defender. I have an alternative solution, which is to use Gradle project, I will post that later if I have time.